# Doubled up approval tasks for a document

Tags: 2013, workflow, approval-process, duplicate

I have a reusable workflow that is being used to approve a document content type (named SWIS).  When a document is submitted for approval it is created double the normal number of approval tasks.  There are 3 approvers, each person needs to approve the document.  However each approver is being assigned 2 tasks for a single document:

[image: picture showing 6x approval tasks, there are 3 approvers in serial]

Here are the workflow settings, accessed via the Document Library settings.

[image: Workflow settings]

When I open this document library with SP Designer, I find that the Start Options here are different.  I'm also a little puzzled by having the Start Options in two places - the workflow itself appears to have different Start Options.  **Could this be causing the duplicate approval tasks?**

So, then we come to the next strange issue, a weird error message.  I had disabled all Start Options on the workflow itself (in SPD, I selected Workflows>Reusable Workflow>SWIS Doc Approval workflow) then I disabled all Start Options.  I tried to Publish the changes and I saw this error!

[image]

I've included two issues in this Question, but they do seem to be linked to each other, as far as I can tell.  I'd be grateful for any pointers anyone can give or any troubleshooting suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the poor answer that follows; I couldn't find the source of the error.  I deleted the workflow and recreated it by copying an existing reusable workflow.  This resulted in having to rename lots of email titles and change customised email text, had to set the approvers group again.

This resolved the issue.